# Minimizing SQL queries using join with one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, mysql

So let me preface this by saying that I'm not an SQL wizard by any means. What I want to do is simple as a concept, but has presented me with a small challenge when trying to minimize the amount of database queries I'm performing.

Let's say I have a table of departments. Within each department is a list of employees.

What is the most efficient way of listing all the departments and which employees are in each department.

**So for example** if I have a department table with:

```
id   name
1    sales
2    marketing
```

And a people table with:

```
id   department_id   name
1    1               Tom
2    1               Bill
3    2               Jessica
4    1               Rachel
5    2               John
```

What is the best way list all departments and all employees for each department like so:

**Sales**

- Tom
- Bill
- Rachel

**Marketing**

- Jessica
- John

Pretend both tables are actually massive. (I want to avoid getting a list of departments, and then looping through the result and doing an individual query for each department). Think similarly of selecting the statuses/comments in a Facebook-like system, when statuses and comments are stored in separate tables.

Comment: +1 for trying to break free of the looping mindset of the imperative programmer. It's well worth it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get it all in a single query with a simple join, e.g.:

```
SELECT   d.name AS 'department', p.name AS 'name'
FROM     department d
  LEFT JOIN people p ON p.department_id = d.id
ORDER BY department
```

This returns all the data, but it's a bit of a pain to consume, since you'll have to iterate through every person anyway. You can go further and group them together:

```
SELECT   d.name AS 'department',
         GROUP_CONCAT(p.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'name'
FROM     department d
  LEFT JOIN people p ON p.department_id = d.id
GROUP BY department
```

You'll get something like this as the output:

```
department | name
-----------|----------------
sales      | Tom, Bill, Rachel
marketing  | Jessica, John
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing I needed. Thanks for the information about GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT in this case. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.name, p.name
FROM department d
JOIN people p ON p.department_id = d.id
```

I suggest also reading a [SQL Join tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) or three. This is a very common and very basic SQL concept that you should understand thoroughly.

Comment: That was a softball wasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This is normally done in a single query:

```
SELECT DepartmentTable.Name, People.Name from DepartmentTable 
INNER JOIN People
ON DepartmentTable.id = People.department_id
ORDER BY DepartmentTable.Name
```

This will suppress empty departments. If you want to show empty departments, change `INNER` to `LEFT OUTER`

Comment: Um, what? This will return all columns from both tables, no? But as long as I'm here I'll add an ORDER BY and make the field names explicit...