# Concatenate multi value into one record

Tags: python

I joined two tables together and what I like to do is concatenate multi vaule in one records without duplicated value.

1. Input Table
   Table name: TAXLOT_ZONE
   TID   ZONE
   1     A
   1     A
   1     B
   1     C
   2     D
   2     D 
   2     E
   3     A
   3     B
   4     C
   5     D
2. Desirable output table looks like;
   table name: Taxlot_zone_out
   TID  ZONE
   1    A, B, C
   2    D, E
   3    A, B
   4    C
   5    D

Comment: There are no such things as "tables" in pure Python. Are you using a database? If so, what kind of interface? SQL? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451026/minimizing-sql-queries-using-join-with-one-to-many-relationship/2451065#2451065

Comment: I use file geodatabase or dbf format which is created by ESRI, GIS company. I just want to create a new table from this joined table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is in sorted order and is iterable, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) to group rows with the same first element.

```
l = [(1, 'A'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (1, 'C'),
     (2, 'D'), (2, 'D'), (2, 'E'),
     (3, 'A'), (3, 'B'),
     (4, 'C'),
     (5, 'D')]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
result = [(taxlot, list(set(v for k,v in g)))
          for taxlot, g in groupby(l, itemgetter(0))]
```

Result:

```
[(1, ['A', 'C', 'B']),
 (2, ['E', 'D']),
 (3, ['A', 'B']),
 (4, ['C']),
 (5, ['D'])]
```