# Make one-to-many relationship look like one-to-one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgres 9.3.5.

Given the following data:

```
select * from department;
 id |   name    
----+-----------
  1 | sales
  2 | marketing
  3 | HR
```

and

```
select * from people;
 id | department_id | first_name | last_name 
----+---------------+------------+-----------
  1 |             1 | Tom        | Jones
  2 |             1 | Bill       | Cosby
  3 |             2 | Jessica    | Biel
  4 |             1 | Rachel     | Hunter
  5 |             2 | John       | Barnes
```

I'd like to return a result set like this:

```
 id |   name    | first_name-1 | last_name-1 | first_name-2 | last_name-2 | first_name-3 | last_name-3
----+-----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------------ 
  1 | sales     | Tom          | Jones       | Bill         | Cosby       | Rachel       | Hunter
  2 | marketing | Jessica      | Biel        | John         | Barnes
  3 | HR        |
```

Is this possible?

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451026/minimizing-sql-queries-using-join-with-one-to-many-relationship) by Max Shawabkeh using the GROUP_CONCAT is close - but its not returning as extra fields in the dataset, its concatenating them into a single field.

Answer (score 1):

You need cross-tabulation (sometimes called *pivot*).

Could look like this in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
       $$SELECT d.id, d.name,'p' AS dummy_cat 
               ,concat_ws(' ', p.first_name, p.last_name) AS person
         FROM   department  d
         LEFT   JOIN people p ON p.department_id = d.id
         ORDER  BY d.department_id, p.id$$
       )
AS ct (id int, department text, person_1 text, person_2 text, person_3 text);
```

Returns:

```
id  department  person_1      person_2     person_3
--------------------------------------------------------
1   sales       Tom Jones     Bill Cosby   Rachel Hunter
2   marketing   Jessica Biel  John Barnes  <NULL>
3   HR          <NULL>        <NULL>       <NULL>
```

*Very* similar to this related case (explanation for special difficulties there):

- [Postgres - Transpose Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns/23061730#23061730)

But this case is simpler: since you do not seem to care about the order in which persons are listed, you can use the basic one-parameter form of `crosstab()`.

Also, according to your comment, you want all departments, even if no people are assigned. Adjusted the LEFT JOIN accordingly.

Basic details in this related answer:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: Thanks Erwin, very close to the output I'm looking for - missing the NULL row for HR and separate columns for first_name and last_name.

Comment: @CodeBuddy: I inverted the `LEFT JOIN` to include empty departments and simplified the query. Separate names, can be solved, too. Decompose in an outer query.

Comment: Thanks again, but new query returns an error for me: ERROR:  column d.department_id does not exist

Comment: @CodeBuddy: Obviously, that's `d.id` (I never use non-descriptive words like "id" or "name" as identifiers in my own designs.)