# SQL/PHP join products table on multiple images table

Tags: php, sql, join

I have *two tables* (**products** and **images**). Images contains with none, one, or even more records per product.

I'd like to join **two images** (if available) **to each product** and display them somehow. I'm talking about **products list**, **not a single product**. Here comes the problem.

Let's say I have these tables:

Products:

```
id     | name
1      | Lenovo V310
2      | Adapter 5v
3      | Mousepad
4      | Gamepad Logitech
5      | Nokia 3210
```

Images:

```
id      | image_name    | product_id
1       | lenovo1.jpg   | 1
2       | lenovo2.jpg   | 1
3       | lenovo3.jpg   | 1
4       | lenovo4.jpg   | 1
5       | mousepad1.jpg | 3
6       | mousepad2.jpg | 3
7       | gamepad1.jpg  | 4
8       | gamepad2.jpg  | 4
9       | nokia1.png    | 5
10      | nokia2.png    | 5
11      | nokia3.png    | 5
12      | nokia4.png    | 5
```

I would like my products (**products list**, *not a single item*) to be displayed with **two images each**:

**Example:** Lenovo V310 + lenovo1.jpg + lenovo2.jpg

I tried it in some ways, but those didn't work. As for example:

```
    $q = "SELECT products.id, products.name, images.image_name FROM products LEFT JOIN images ON products.id = (SELECT product_id FROM images) LIMIT 6";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $image1 = $row['image_name']; // ain't working also with the query above
        $image2 = $row['image_name']; // how to take the second img????
        ..............
```

Comment: [I think this will helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451026/minimizing-sql-queries-using-join-with-one-to-many-relationship/2451065#2451065)

Comment: Do you have access to latest version of MySQL (8.0.2. and above) ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

SQL:

```
SELECT p.id,
    p.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(i.image_name ORDER BY i.image_name) AS images
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN images i ON p.id = i.product_id
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 6;
```

PHP:

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $images = explode(',', $row['images']);
    $image1 = (count($images) > 0) ? $images[0] : null;
    $image2 = (count($images) > 1) ? $images[1] : null;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest `$images = explode(',', $row['images']);` and then assign `$image1` and `$image2` as needed from that array. Also: why do you have `LIMIT 6` in your query?

Comment: Agreed @DaanWilmer thanks. Have updated the answer. For the `LIMIT 6` it was in the original query so I kept it.

Comment: I've just tried the solution. Now I have something new to study :) GROUP_CONCAT. Interesting. For a newbie it's not that easy. Regarding your question about the LIMIT 6 - just imagine 6 best selling products on the front page. Where is nothing special about that. Sorry if it confused you. You probably thought that I was trying to limit some images or something else. LOVELY done. Cheers

Comment: Hi, agreed it is not that easy, I have discovered `GROUP_CONCAT` after like seven years of experience on PHP development, just remember it is a grouping function as is the `SUM` or `MAX` functions, so you usually would have a column with repeated values (here the `p.id` column) and you group with this column, and then you do what you want with the values that was grouped on the other columns (here we was interested in the `i.image_name` column).

Comment: @ankabout In addition, if someone knows where am I supposed to insert WHERE clause, please let me know. I'd like to show only active products, so I tried to insert `WHERE products.status = 1` at some different positions, but the query has failed.

Comment: @Jurgen The `Where` should be between the `LEFT JOIN` clause and the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @ankabout I've already tried all the possible positions. And no results. I'll keep looking for the solution.